# Download videos using django didn't work with Iphone

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Why download videos from django doesn't work with Iphone but it's work with android and windows

my view

```
def download_videos(request, pk):
video = Video.objects.get(pk=pk)
response = HttpResponse(
    video.video,
    content_type='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="fromCubeLinda.mp4"'
return response
```

The html template

```
         <a id="adown" href="{% url 'video:video_download' video.pk %}" target="_blank">Download</a>
```